# Quick way to modify large Dictionary Values

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I have a large dictionary, each value itself is a large list.

I have to go through each value and remove members that don't follow this pattern:

"Each member which is smaller than the previous member should be smaller than the next member or if the member is greater than the previous member then it should be greater than the next number too."

This is what I have tried:

```
Nodes = {1:[2,...,3],..., 2:[3,...5]} # a short example of the big dict
for key in Nodes.keys():
    for i in range(1, len(Nodes[key])-1):
        if Nodes[key][i-1] < Nodes [key][i] < Nodes[key][i+1] or Nodes[key][i-1] > Nodes [key][i] > Nodes[key][i+1]:
            del Nodes[key][i]
```

And this is what I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
if Nodes[key][i-1] < Nodes [key][i] < Nodes[key][i+1] or Nodes[key][i-1] > Nodes [key][i] > Nodes[key][i+1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

One thing I can predict is that the operator deletes the list member right away then the list messes up, because when I tried to check this by printing the list member instead of deleting it, the code worked.

Comment: Don't modify a list you are iterating over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One thing I can predict is that the operator deletes the list member
>   right away then the list messes up, because when I tried to check this
>   by printing the list member instead of deleting it, the code worked.

You are right. And as @Daniel said, "Don't modify a list you are iterating over."

You can create a new list, append all the valid values to new list, and assign key in the dict this new list.

```
Nodes = {1:[2,...,3],..., 2:[3,...5]} # a short example of the big dict
for key in Nodes.keys():
    new_list = list()
    for i in range(1, len(Nodes[key])-1):
        if not( Nodes[key][i-1] < Nodes [key][i] < Nodes[key][i+1] or Nodes[key][i-1] > Nodes [key][i] > Nodes[key][i+1]):
            new_list.append(Nodes[key][i])
    Nodes[key] = new_list
```